# @Published array in multiple ViewModels - SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, viewmodel, shared

I have app with only two Views, both Views has own ViewModel. ViewA shows and manipulate objects from selectedNumbers array. ViewB owns all available objects(numbers) - in this view I want manipulate selectedNumbers array, that is used by ViewA.

I'm trying to find out, how to share these selectedNumbers array between these two ViewModels. I tried to use EnvironmentObject, StaticObject etc. But nothing works as I need. What approach should I use to achieve desired result. Thanks for help!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewA: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModelA()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(viewModel.number)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.showNext()
                }
            ViewB()
        }
    }
}

class ViewModelA: ObservableObject {
    var numbers: [Int] = []
    @Published var number: Int
    var index = 0

    init() {
        number = numbers.isEmpty ? 0 : numbers[index]
    }

    func showNext() {
        guard !numbers.isEmpty else { return }
        if index < numbers.count - 1 {
            index += 1
        } else {
            index = 0
        }
        number = numbers[index]
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModelB()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                Text("\(number)")
                    .foregroundColor(viewModel.selectedNumbers.contains(number) ? .red : .black)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.updateSelection(number)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModelB: ObservableObject {
    @Published var numbers: [Int] = []
    @Published var selectedNumbers: [Int] = []

    init() {
        numbers.append(contentsOf: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
    }

    func updateSelection(_ number: Int) {
        if selectedNumbers.contains(number) {
            selectedNumbers.remove(number)
        } else {
            selectedNumbers.append(number)
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func remove(_ object: Element) {
        guard let index = firstIndex(of: object) else {return}
        remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two different source of truth, you should rethink your model design using bindings, and keep single source of truth

Comment: What do you mean? Use just one ViewModel -> ViewModelA and Bind it to ViewB? I tried to separate logic of these two views..

Answer (score 2):

You can still keep the logic separate, but you need to keep a ***single source of truth***, and if you want to share data among views, you either need to pass `Bindings` or you can also share `@ObservedObject` among Subviews.

```
import SwiftUI


struct ViewA: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModelA(modelB: ViewModelB())

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(viewModel.number)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.showNext()
                }
            ViewB(model: viewModel)
        }
    }
}

class ViewModelA: ObservableObject {
    
    var numbers: [Int] = []
    
    @Published var number: Int
    @Published var modelB:ViewModelB
    
    var index = 0

    init(modelB:ViewModelB) {
        self.modelB = modelB
        number = numbers.isEmpty ? 0 : modelB.selectedNumbers[index]
    }

    func showNext() {
        guard !modelB.selectedNumbers.isEmpty else { return }
        if index < modelB.selectedNumbers.count - 1 {
            index += 1
        } else {
            index = 0
        }
        number = modelB.selectedNumbers[index]
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {

    @ObservedObject var model : ViewModelA

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(model.modelB.selectedNumbers, id: \.self) { number in
                Text("\(number)")
                    .foregroundColor(model.modelB.selectedNumbers.contains(number) ? .red : .black)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        model.modelB.updateSelection(number)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewModelB {
    
    var selectedNumbers: [Int] = []

    init() {
        selectedNumbers.append(contentsOf: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
    }

   mutating func updateSelection(_ number: Int) {
        if selectedNumbers.contains(number) {
            selectedNumbers.remove(number)
        } else {
            selectedNumbers.append(number)
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func remove(_ object: Element) {
        guard let index = firstIndex(of: object) else {return}
        remove(at: index)
    }
}
```